# Modifying style of ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have been using [LevelScheme](https://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) for a short time. In the beginning I was just trying to increase the size of the ticks in my plots and `LinTicks` worked pretty well. But now I am making plots for a more serious type of work and I want to make them look as good as possible.

---

I have the following list of points:

```
points={{0.5, 5.28788}, {0.75, 5.06717}, {1., 4.65195}, {1.25, 
  3.61722}, {1.5, 2.64618}, {1.75, 2.16506}, {2., 1.94835}, {2.25, 
  1.80968}, {2.5, 1.71555}, {2.75, 1.65771}, {3., 1.61147}}
```

and then I just interpolate them

```
f = Interpolation[points]
```

Now, after I load the LevelScheme package, I set the length of the minor and major ticks by typing

```
SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.02, 0}, 
  MinorTickLength -> {0.013, 0}];
```

and finally I create the plot

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {1, 5.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0049], Darker[Brown]}, 
 Axes -> {False, False}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], FrameTicks -> LinTicks, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20], Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

The output is the following

[image]

The problems that I'm having are the following:

1)The length of the ticks is perfect, but I would like to change the number of minor ticks in between two major ticks (say, one minor tick between two major ticks) and I don't know how to do that.

2)Also, I would like to make the tick labels **on the x-axis only** appear every 0.5 units while the tick labels **on the y-axis** appear every 1 units. I tried adding `TickLabelStep -> 0.5` to the `SetOptions` function above but it doesn't change anything. It only works when I enter a positive integer number.

3)Finally, I would like to get rid of the tick labels that appear on the right and top of the frame, so that only the bottom and left sides of the box have tick labels. I've tried many things, such as adding `FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 4, 0.5,5], LinTicks[0, 7, 1, 2],  LinTicks[0, 4, 0.5, 5, ShowTickLabels -> False],  LinTicks[0, 7, 1, 5, ShowTickLabels -> False]}` but it doesn't work.

This is a plot that fulfills most of my requests:
[image]

I'm sure LevelScheme is not the only way to do all this, so I'm open to any suggestions even if they don't use LevelScheme at all.
I'd be grateful if somebody could help me improve my plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the (undocumented) function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` which allows specification of the number and lengths for major and minor ticks:

```
tickFunction = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
  "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {5, 2}]&;

Quiet @ Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> {1, 5.5}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0049], Darker[Brown]}, 
    Axes -> {False, False}, 
    Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
    FrameTicks -> Table[tickFunction, 2, 2], 
    FrameTicksStyle -> ({#, #} & @ {FontSize -> 20, FontOpacity -> 0}), 
    ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Replace `{5, 2}` with `{5, 1}` or `5` to get:

[image]